# Error: Binding reference of type .. to const

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload operator<<. When trying I got an error saying

`Error: Passing const as this argument discards qualifiers`

So I added const to my functions but now I'm getting this error:

`Binding reference of type .. to const.`

**Main.cpp**

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Student& stud){
    float mo = 0;
    int quantity = stud.get_grade().size();\
.
.
.
```

**Get_grade Function**

```
vector<pair<Subject *, float>>& Student::get_grade() const{
    return grade;
}
```

**Error**

```
binding reference of type ‘std::vector<std::pair<Subject*, float> >&’ to ‘const std::vector<std::pair<Subject*, float> >’ discards qualifiers
| return grade;
```

Grade is a vector

Comment: You need `const` in front of the function too. i.e. `const vector<pair<Subject *, float>>& Student::get_grade() const{`

Comment: OK seems to work, but is this bad practice?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, no. I would argue that converting the result of `.size()` to `int` is bad practice thought. `.size()` returns `size_t`, which is unsigned, and can be much larger than `int`.

Comment: So that means I should change int to unsgned int?

Comment: @InvalidInput Why do you want to convert the result to `unsigned int`? Why not just declare the `quantity` variable as `std::size_t` as well to avoid unnecessary conversion? For example, on x64 Windows, `std::size_t` is 64-bit, while `unsigned int` is still 32-bit.

Comment: Oh thanks for the mention! Will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_grade` is a **const member function** meaning that the type of `this` pointer inside it is `const Student*` which in turn means that the data member `grade` is treated as if it were itself `const`. But the **problem is** that the return type of your function is an *lvalue reference to non-const `std::vector`* meaning it cannot be bound to a `const std::vector`.

To **solve** this just add a low-level `const` in the return type of the function as shown below:

```
vvvvv------------------------------------------------------------->low-level const added
const vector<pair<Subject *, float>>& Student::get_grade() const{
    return grade;
}
```